# NSInternalConsistencyException thrown when loading a NIB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sigabrt

I have an RSS feed reader with a table view.  When I run my app, it boots up fine, but when I try to touch one of the previews of the articles in the table view, I get a SIGABRT error/warning. When I look in the debugger console, the reason that comes up is as follows:

```
2011-08-10 23:39:51.224 Ross Mobile[7733:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/dev-shamilton14/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/FA486D34-1D22-49BD-9DAB-C660F4209AA2/Ross Mobile.app> (loaded)' with name 'Detail''
```

Please help me to figure out what I need to do to fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you need to create Detail.xib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer didn't directly fix the problem, but it did point me in the right way to solving the problem, and now im problem free!

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the one line you posted, there's something wrong with your NIB file, or you are not referencing it correctly. Make sure that your NIB file is called "Detail.xib", and that it exists.

Whenever you call something like `SomeNib *newInstance = [SomeNib alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil]`, you need to make sure that your NIB file exists, is called @"SomeNib" (or whatever you passed in to that method) and that there are no "broken" outlet connections. (That is, all outlets that are connected in the NIB must exist in code.) If not, you'll get the crash you're seeing.